# How can I make my posts on my home page just show summaries?

Tags: homepage, customization

My [home page](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk) lists all my recent posts, however it displays each post in its entirety. Is there any way I can force it to just show a preview, such as the first 10 lines?

This would enable views to quickly scroll through and see the topics recently blogged, rather than having to scroll through a recent post which is incredibly large.

(this also helps with more Ad impressions I believe)

Under Settings > Reading, there is the following option `For each article in a feed, show ...Full Text / Summary` but I think this is only for feeds (RSS).

Thanks

---

Answer (score 2):

First you can use the more-Tag when writing the post. WordPress will only Show the Part before the more-Tag and Show a Read-more-Link.

You can open the file with the Loop in the Active theme (normally index.php), Search for the_content(...) and replace it with the_excerpt().

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_home_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 500; //about ten lines
}

function my_home_post_cropper($content) {
    if (!is_page() && (is_front_page() || is_home())) {
        add_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_home_excerpt_length');
        $content = wp_trim_excerpt($content);
        remove_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_home_excerpt_length');
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'my_home_post_cropper', 99);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might make use of the excerpt field on the post editing page to contain your post summary - this way, you can write specifically what you want to be shown on the homepage. You can then display the custom except by calling `the_excerpt()` in your homepage template.

I think this gives you more control than a text truncating solution as has been suggested.